# Goodness Of Fit Testing When Multiple Parameters Are Estimated

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, lilliefors-test

I am working with independent data points $X_1,...,X_N$ each of which, under my model assumptions, is a sum of exponential waiting times with different rates, and so should come from gamma distributions with the same shape but different rates, i.e. $X_n \sim \textit{Gamma}\left(\alpha,\beta_n\right)$ for $n \in \{1,...,N\}$. $\alpha$ is known already but for each $\beta_n$ I have to estimate its value from the data using the known waiting times.

I want to test this hypothesis using some sort of goodness of fit test and so I started by calculating $Y_n\colon=\beta_nX_n$ for each n as this should then come a $\textit{Gamma}\left(\alpha,1\right)$ distribution. And so I would then have N, independent $\textit{Gamma}\left(\alpha,1\right)$ I could apply a goodness of fit test to.

I saw that if the parameters for the distribution are estimated from the data, the appropriate test would be a Lilliefors test. However the examples I have read concerns data $Z_1,...Z_N$ all of which are presumed to come from the same distribution whilst in my case each one comes from a gamma distribution with different parameters all of which have been estimated from the data.

Hence I am slightly confused where to go next, can I simply run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Lilliefors test on my transformed data $Y_n$ (testing for a $\textit{Gamma}\left(\alpha,1\right)$ distribution) or am I missing something? Any reference material would be greatly appreciated too.